# AutoIt - TCPListen working for local connections but not for global ones

Tags: tcp, automation, ip, autoit

I am trying to send messages between computers using AutoIt TCPListen and TCPConnect function. It works fine on local machine and on the computers that are sharing my local network. But when I try to use it on global connections, it fails. In other words

```
TCPListen("127.0.0.1",33891)
```

or

```
TCPListen("192.168.0.105",33891)
```

is working fine but when I try this global IP:

```
TCPListen("131.160.148.126",33891)
```

is does not work. Is it possible to communicate using your public IP address? If yes, then please tell me where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the TCP functions on a global scale you must make sure you port forward the data recieved from that port to the machine you would like to see it on.

Here is a guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-Port-Forwarding-on-a-Router